# Ng-repeat does not render when in a div with overflow:auto style

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I apologize for not providing a working example of this, but every time I recreate the bug in a simplified version on Plnkr it works. I am embarrassed by this, but also incredibly stumped.

I am therefore asking your help in identifying what the problem could theoretically be that's causing this.

Basically, my factory listens for an event from my websocket, and $broadcast a message to my controller. There I concat the incoming data from the backend server to the front-end list of objects. I created a Plnkr here with the basic concept: http://plnkr.co/edit/RbBgZkRsGAb7RhvvExb3

What ends up happening is that the div the ng-repeat is in, goes blank. As in all the items disappear. In order to fix this, I have to reset the array and do:

```
    var joinedNewsLinks = $scope.news;
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.news = []; 
    });
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.news = joinedNewsLinks;
    });
```

I have to enter the digest loop with my links blank, and then re-digest them with the values I want.

I can't reproduce this error on plnkr so I am looking for potential theoretical problems this could be caused by? If I remove the height:100px styling, everything works as intended and ng-repeat renders just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you try pusing values directly in $scope.news ???

Comment: I have tried using both push and unshift, and it results in the same issue (blanking out my div)

Comment: I'm sorry but without a sample of the broken code it's impossible to help you. Anyway the call to apply is really redundant, you should simply update the contents of the array. Don't mess with angular digest process unless you absolutely need to.

Comment: Wow, I changed the span in the Plnkr to a div and everything worked fine. So if I do ng-repeat in the div instead of the span, it works...

Comment: Yes, @MatteoMosca I agree - hence why I was embarassed to post this. But I fixed it by changing span to div in my comment. Hopefully as time progresses, I will learn more of the internals and be able to explain deeper as to why this happened. Thank you for your patience and the kind time you took to respond to a question such as this.